# Erro de sintaxe na consulta ao banco Informix

Tags: query, sintaxe, informix

Fiz um protótipo de um banco de dados `informix` no *Access* para otimizar a construção de minhas consultas. Eu uso com o *MySQL* e mediante algumas adaptações nas sintaxes eu consigo numa boa.

Porém no `informix`eu não estou conseguindo. Quero crer que seja um pequeno detalhe mas não estou encontrando.

Os relacionamentos entre as tabelas são esses que eu configurei no *Access*:

[image: Query do Access]

A consulta ao banco `informix` eu fiz da seguinte maneira:

```
SELECT cnnfcapa.tpordem, cnnfcapa.id_agente, cnnfcapa.id_agentvext,
cmgrupos.id_grupos, cnnfitem.desritem, cnnfitem.mercadoria,
cnnfitem.quantidade, cnnfitem.valoritem, 0 AS rsrv,
(cnnfitem.valoritem-cnnfitem.customedio`) AS lprd
FROM cmgrupos
INNER JOIN cscapas
INNER JOIN cnnfcapa
INNER JOIN cnnfitem ON cnnfcapa.id_nfcapa = cnnfitem.id_nfcapa
AND cscapas.ordemserv = cnnfcapa.ordemserv
INNER JOIN cttransa ON cnnfcapa.transacao = cttransa.transacao
AND cmgrupos.id_grupos = cnnfitem.idgrupos
INNER JOIN cipessoa
INNER JOIN ciendere ON cipessoa.cgccpf = ciendere.cgccpf
AND cnnfcapa.nro_proprietario = ciendere.nro_endere
WHERE cnnfitem.tpitem "<>2"
AND cttransa.mvtotransacao Like "S"
AND cttransa.tipotransacao Like 10
```

Onde será que eu estou errando?

Comment: o que quer dizer com "não estou conseguindo"? a consulta retorna errada? retorna algum erro? qual??

Comment: Retorna erro de sintaxe

Comment: Pode colocar a mensagem do erro?

Comment: "201: A syntax error has occurred"